# MongoDB Aggregation combining both 'max' of EACH document and 'sum' of ALL documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I am recording golf scores and now trying to calculate the leaderboards. This is for use on a PHP site, so I also need to translate the pipeline code (afterwards!).

Each `round` document has a sub-array of `holes`:

```
{
  "playerName": "Tiger Woods", 
  "comp": {
    "name": "US Open 2021", 
    "courseId": "608952e3abebbd503ba6e115", 
    "scoringMethod": "Stableford", 
    "tees": "Blue", 
    "courseName": "MAGC Middle 9", 
    "roundNo": 2, 
    "id": {
      "$oid": "607019361c071256e4f0d0d5"
    }
  }, 
  "holes": [
    {
      "blue": 431, 
      "holeNett": 4, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 5, 
      "no": 1, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 420, 
      "si": 2, 
      "holeStrokes": 1, 
      "white": 444, 
      "red": 399
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 335, 
      "holeNett": 5, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 5, 
      "no": 2, 
      "holeNettPoints": 1, 
      "yellow": 320, 
      "si": 8, 
      "holeStrokes": 0, 
      "white": 350, 
      "red": 295
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 385, 
      "holeNett": 4, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 5, 
      "no": 3, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 362, 
      "si": 4, 
      "holeStrokes": 1, 
      "white": 400, 
      "red": 343
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 161, 
      "holeNett": 3, 
      "par": 3, 
      "holeGross": 3, 
      "no": 4, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 144, 
      "si": 7, 
      "holeStrokes": 0, 
      "white": 180, 
      "red": 105
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 461, 
      "holeNett": 5, 
      "par": 5, 
      "holeGross": 6, 
      "no": 5, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 439, 
      "si": 1, 
      "holeStrokes": 1, 
      "white": 473, 
      "red": 418
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 330, 
      "holeNett": 4, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 4, 
      "no": 6, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 300, 
      "si": 9, 
      "holeStrokes": 0, 
      "white": 337, 
      "red": 281
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 381, 
      "holeNett": 6, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 6, 
      "no": 7, 
      "holeNettPoints": 0, 
      "yellow": 363, 
      "si": 5, 
      "holeStrokes": 0, 
      "white": 390, 
      "red": 290
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 152, 
      "holeNett": 3, 
      "par": 3, 
      "holeGross": 3, 
      "no": 8, 
      "holeNettPoints": 2, 
      "yellow": 140, 
      "si": 6, 
      "holeStrokes": 0, 
      "white": 167, 
      "red": 131
    }, 
    {
      "blue": 366, 
      "holeNett": 3, 
      "par": 4, 
      "holeGross": 4, 
      "no": 9, 
      "holeNettPoints": 3, 
      "yellow": 344, 
      "si": 3, 
      "holeStrokes": 1, 
      "white": 396, 
      "red": 327
    }
  ], 
  "playerId": "609d0993906429612483cea0", 
  "holeCount": 9, 
  "countbackScores": [
    16, 
    11, 
    5, 
    2
  ], 
  "team": "magc", 
  "date": "2021-05-20T23:00:00+00:00", 
  "computedScore": 16, 
  "computedThru": 9, 
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a6aa828078924a6065dc9e"
  }
}
```

I have an aggregation pipeline that finds the highest or lowest (competition rules dependent) score on every hole. I had to `$unwind` the sub-array, producing a pipeline document per hole played. Typically this means either 18 documents or 9 for a half-round, per player. Also to note, each `round` could be played on a different `comp.courseId` (there are 3 courses in my initial comp) - so these need to be grouped by as well, hence it is currently in my `$match` filter.

Can I in the same pipeline calculate the cumulative total of final pipeline output, at the same time as retaining the previous documents?

```
[{$match: {
    "comp.id" : ObjectId('600019361c071256e4f0d0d5'),
    "playerId" : "600d0993906429612483cea0",
    "comp.courseId" : "600955aaabebbd503ba6e116"
}
}, 
{$unwind: {
  path : "$holes"
}}, 
{$group: {
  _id: "$holes.no",
  hole: {
    $max: "$holes"
  }
}}, 
{$set: {
  "total": { "$sum" : "$hole.holeNettPoints" }
}}, 
{$sort: {
  "hole.no": 1
}
}]
```

The `$set` pipeline is the stage I am testing at. But this only sums the `holeNettPoints` field, from a single document, so is the same as this value in each document.

I don't think I can do another `$group` of all these documents, as on my PHP page though, I need the other per-hole fields to build an HTML table. But its sorted by the cumulative total for the round. So I have tried adding a field with `$set`. Is this correct?

This returns a document per hole played (9 with my current data, commonly 18 for a full round of golf). I would like to have the cumulative `holeNettPoints` total for all 9 holes as well as the `$max` per hole `holeNettPoints` across each player on each `courseId`. Something of the structure:

```
playerId = 123456
courseId = abcdef
total = 18
holes = (
    ([no] => 1, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 2, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 3, [holeNettPoints] => 3),
    ([no] => 4, [holeNettPoints] => 1),
    ([no] => 5, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 6, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 7, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 8, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
    ([no] => 9, [holeNettPoints] => 2),
)
```

Ideally, the result would return a single document, and then I would be able to remove the `playerId` `$match` filter so that it would work across the many players who would play in each comp.

I would prefer that MongoDB uses aggregation to return the formatted and sorted result, so PHP can just loop through it's results.

Comment: can you show your expected result..

Comment: expanded / amended the description to include more details. expands on previous / similar thread but is a different topic to $sum a grouped $max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` by `playerId`, `courseId` and `no` and get max of `holeNettPoints`
- `$group` by `playerId` and construct the array of `holes` with `no` and `holeNettPoints` and also get total of all `holeNettPoints`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "comp.id": ObjectId("607019361c071256e4f0d0d5"),
      "playerId": "609d0993906429612483cea0",
      "comp.courseId": "608952e3abebbd503ba6e115"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$holes" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        playerId: "$playerId",
        courseId: "$comp.courseId",
        no: "$holes.no"
      },
      holeNettPoints: { $max: "$holes.holeNettPoints" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.playerId",
      courseId: { $first: "$_id.courseId" },
      holes: {
        $push: {
          no: "$_id.no",
          holeNettPoints: "$holeNettPoints"
        }
      },
      total: { $sum: "$holeNettPoints" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o_oOnEFSBm8)

---

PHP syntax:

```php
$query = [
  [
    '$match' => [
      'comp.id' => ObjectId("607019361c071256e4f0d0d5"),
      'playerId' => "609d0993906429612483cea0",
      'comp.courseId' => "608952e3abebbd503ba6e115"
    ]
  ],
  [ '$unwind' => [ 'path' => '$holes' ] ],
  [
    '$group' => [
      '_id' => [
        'playerId' => '$playerId',
        'courseId' => '$comp.courseId',
        'no' => '$holes.no'
      ],
      'holeNettPoints' => [ '$max' => '$holes.holeNettPoints' ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    '$group' => [
      '_id' => '$_id.playerId',
      'courseId' => [ '$first' => '$_id.courseId' ],
      'holes' => [
        '$push' => [
          'no' => '$_id.no',
          'holeNettPoints' => '$holeNettPoints'
        ]
      ],
      'total' => [ '$sum' => '$holeNettPoints' ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: great stuff, @turivishal! exactly as asked. And I'm starting to get some background to the framework. Can I ask if you are only using the `"_id"` array to pass the same data through the stages and otherwise they would be lost / filtered out?

Comment: i am not getting you, `_id` array? if you are talking about `$group` stage you need to pass data that you want in next stage.

Comment: in the `$group` stage, you put `playerId` and `courseId` into the `_id` field, to make it an array (compound key in RDBMS speak??). if you didn't include them in this stage, you wouldn't be able to use them later. Otherwise you need to perform some aggregator function on them (sum, first, etc). But to just pull through the original value, this is how you do it?

Comment: when you understand the meaning of **group** it will group some data, but **by what it will group?** so `_id` will take place, `_id` said give me the name of fields I will do group by that field's value (it will find the distinct/unique value of that provided field(s) and documents),